# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function entity_crud_get_info() in #########\docroot\sites ... in xxx/modules/entity/entity.rules.inc on line 96

Tags: 7, rules, entities, wsod

I am getting the above error whenever I install the module.
The above errors keep occuring on every page.
How can I debug it or solve it?
I am clueless and working for a solution 
Any pointers would be helpful.

```
https://www.drupal.org/node/2238251
```

The above link also has same issue but no fix provided
I am pasting the debug_backtrace provided :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /includes/bootstrap.inc [line] => 1112 [function] => include_once ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /includes/module.inc [line] => 24 [function] => drupal_load [args] => Array ( [0] => module [1] => custom_sarres ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => /includes/common.inc [line] => 5126 [function] => module_load_all [args] => Array ( ) ) [3] => Array ( [file] => /includes/bootstrap.inc [line] => 2267 [function] => _drupal_bootstrap_full [args] => Array ( ) ) [4] => Array ( [file] => /index.php [line] => 20 [function] => drupal_bootstrap [args] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) ) ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function libraries_get_path() /sites/all/modules/feeds/feeds.module on line 1021
```

Comment: Make sure the Entity API module is present in one of the  module paths

Comment: please let me know clearly about what does the module path mean?

Comment: sites/all/modules or sites/[sitename]/modules are the most likely

Comment: I have entity module installed at "sites/all/modules/entity"

Comment: So if that is proper what can be other reason .Please let me know

Comment: According to the bug report it might be a permissions issue on the sites folder. Beyond that I don't know I'm afraid

Comment: If you have the module and are still getting the error, is there any chance you didn't turn it on?

Comment: thanks but I have entity module turned on but stil getting the error

Comment: the error message clearly says the function is undefined i.e. it is missing.  you can try downloading the module and replacing the existing code. :)  and make sure you work with backup

Comment: thanks but I had tried that as well but it did not work